# Best choose of substrings for dictionary based compression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, optimization, compression

I have a string that need to be compressed by a dictionary compression algorithm. If a substring is found in the dictionary, it is encoded with cost 2. If no match is found, the cost will be the size of the substring. **Given a fixed dictionary** and a string, how could I chose the best substrings in the dictionary resulting in the minimum cost?

For example, consider the string ABBBBBCD and the following dictionary:

- entry 1 - ABBB
- entry 2 - BBCD
- entry 3 - BBBBB
- entry 4 - ABBBB
- entry 5 - CD

The best solution is to chose ABBB and BBCD, resulting in cost 2 + 2 = 4.

If I choose A, BBBBB, C and D, the cost would be 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 5, that is worst than the first.

Yet, if I choose ABBBB, B, CD, the cost will be 2 + 1 + 2 = 5.

After the explanations, my question is: is there a known algorithm that solves this problem? Or, is there some known algorithm that could be modified in order that I can solve the problem not using brute force method?

Please, ask me if something is not clear.

Comment: This problem feels like it could NP-complete (think set cover problem), but I am not an expert on that.

Comment: The dictionary-based compression algorithms that I am familiar with use a greedy match from each new start position rather than attempting to find an ideal encoding.

Comment: I tried a greedy strategy to solve the problem, but the total cost of the compressed data was bigger than the original compressed data (I don't know how it was encoded, but I have the compressed string. My goal is to compress with the same cost than the original or lower, if it is possible)

Comment: You can try dynamic programming - as far as I remember, starting from the end was more popular.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate and solve it as a shortest path problem.

Create a graph with each index as a vertex. Now add a directed edge from i to j (i

Now find the shortest path from index 1 to n. (See: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/ )

Comment: It is a interesting approach, but how I would manage the case of a dictionary entry that need to be used more than one time? It would result in a cycle in the graph.

Comment: @Eloi The edges are directed and are from i to j (where i<j) forming a DAG. So there cannot be cycles.  You can use the same term in the dictionary as many times as you want. It does not matter.